# Android ListView sorting problem

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to create Gridview similar to WPF datagrid i don't know how many of you know about WPF data grid i'll explain its like having header row and rows to bind and whenever i click on each column of header row, the column 'll be sorted. But in this android list view i didn't see any header like in WPF but sorting is there and it'll sorted irrespective of column i.e. when i click on first column at row position '0' all columns 'll be sorted including header row (means header row going downwards) so how can i slove my problem?

Thanks,
@nag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you just want a header row in your listview? Call listView.addHeaderView() passing it the view/layout you want in the header.

Comment: Can you please provide me any sample.

Comment: Also could you please tell me after adding this header view how can i do column wise sorting?